# Let users run arbitrary queries our MySQL database safely

Tags: c++, mysql

We provide various service to our clients, for example, sending emails etc. Their  users are saved in our databases (MySQL). We would like to give an ability to our clients to run arbitrary search on our database without compromising our database. Let me elaborate:

Below is an existing table definition

```
 * User Table
   - email          varchar
   - category       integer
```

Currently the only way our clients can select group of users for whom an action to be taken (say, sending an email) is by sending us a category. They send us category and we take action for all the users in that category.

However, this is quite restrictive and there are times where it would be desired to run custom searches by our clients in an unrestricted way. For example, below is our new table

```
 * User Table
   - email          varchar
   - category       integer
   - gender         integer 
   - dob            integer 
   - country        varchar
```

and we would like our clients to run arbitrary searches on their users using all the fields mentioned, at least logical AND, OR, % (like), () operations to begin with, for example,

```
 (gender = 1 AND dob < 1999) OR category = 2.
```

The idea is that they pass us a subquery which we append to 'SELECT' statement in WHERE clause. However, this is risky and we want to ensure that we tackle this safely without compromising our database by any malicious attempt to exploit this feature. And hence I need your help/inputs.

What would be the safest way to go about providing this kind of ability to search users safely? We use C++ for our backend. Client supplies logic using REST API which will be received by our C++ backend.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is probably to use a prepared statement.  Difficulties arise, because, using your second `User` table as an example, a customer could potentially request a query whose `WHERE` clause involves any combination of the 5 columns in that table.

One trick which might work is something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE
    email    = COALESCE(?, email)    AND
    category = COALESCE(?, category) AND
    gender   = COALESCE(?, gender)   AND
    age      = COALESCE(?, age)      AND
    country  = COALESCE(?, country);
```

The basic idea is that you have a single prepared statement, to which you always bind parameters for all columns in the `Users` table.  If a customer makes a request which does not involve a certain column, then you bind `NULL`, and that condition in the `WHERE` clause effectively gets ignored.

The exact solution you use would depend on the programming language you are using to expose MySQL.

Comment: Tim, thanks, however idea is that client should be able to provide logic like mentioned above. Things would have been simple if we just have to compare (=). Client will send us logic string like I mentioned above and we should be able to use that logic in our query, for example, (gender = 1 AND dob < 1999) OR category = 2.

Comment: I gave a general answer, which probably can be made to work with what you just mentioned.  If you want more details, tell us how you built the website, what language you used, etc.

Comment: We use C++ for our backend. Client supplies logic using REST API which will be received by our C++ backend. So answer to your question is C++

Comment: Thanks.  I am suggesting using one or more flexible prepared statements.  This avoids the problem of SQL injection.  You can build a query using concatenation, but you'll have to sterilize it, and that could be a lot of work.